# impact of inductor and capacitor at resonance

Tags: capacitor, inductor, resonance

It is said that inductor and capacitor cancle each others effect during resonance bt do they still have any effect on the circuit??

Comment: Which circuit do you mean?

Comment: I think you're talking about a simple RLC circuit with all elements in series? What other effect are you talking about? At resonant frequency, the current is simply the voltage divided by the resistance (not the impedance)  and the phase of the current does not lead or lag the voltage but is exactly parallel to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parallel resonant circuit of L and C, at the correct frequency, current taken by the inductor will be the same as the current taken by the capacitor except the sign of one will be the opposite of the other.

So if you have +i and -i going into a node, the net effect is that node appears to have infinite impedance. At lower frequencies the node will look inductive and at higher frequencies it will look capacitive.

If L and C are in series they must share the same current and the voltage across L will be equal and opposite to that across C at resonance - the net effect is that there appears to be 0 volts across the pair but because current flows, series combination of L and C must have zero impedance.

Below resonance, the circuit looks capacitive and above resonance the circuit looks inductive.